# Inside Toggle Switch how to set text values in android

Tags: android, textview, toggleswitch

Hi in the below code i have a custom toggleswitch in that text names for on/off are DAY/Night.
am just displaying some defaults values for day 6 to 18 numbers .If am selecting day want to show 6 to 18 numbers.
If am selecting night means i want to display 19 to 5.
can any one please help me

Toggleswitch.xml:

```
<com.github.angads25.toggle.LabeledSwitch
    android:id="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:colorBorder="@color/colorAccent"
    app:colorOn="#2a9ed1"
    app:on="true"
    app:textOff="NIGHT"
    app:textOn="DAY" />
```

Switch.java:

```
simpleSwitch1.setOnToggledListener(new OnToggledListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSwitched(LabeledSwitch labeledSwitch, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Switch-checked");
            dValue1.setText("9");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is dValue1?

Comment: it's a textview

Comment: what is not working in your code?

Comment: value 9 is not displaying

Comment: if am selecting day means want to display some numbers like 6 to 18 hours.same like night means it 19 to 5 hours

Comment: try to show a toast and check if its working?

Comment: Toast message was displaying

Comment: then there is problem in your xml or style. check how have you added your textview.

Comment: working fine....................